# How to use PaStreamCallbackDelegate in C#

Tags: c#, callback, delegates, stream, portaudio

I need to pass a Callback function to the **Pa_OpenDefaultStream** using a **PaStreamCallbackDelegate** so that I can start the Stream.
I looked on the internet as you do, but also doing as described, it gives me this error:

*no overload for StreamCallback corresponding to the delegate PortAudio.PaStreamCallbackDelegate*

I do not know how to solve it. I know little about the **C#** language and I'm only now beginning to use the library **PortAudio**.

Here I post my code:

```
unsafe public PortAudio.PaStreamCallbackResult StreamCallback(
        IntPtr* input,
        IntPtr* output,
        uint frameCount,
        ref PortAudio.PaStreamCallbackTimeInfo timeInfo,
        PortAudio.PaStreamCallbackFlags statusFlags,
        IntPtr* userData) 
    {
        //Aggiungi roba
        int i;

        for (i = 0; i < frameCount; i++)
        {
             output++;           //LEFT
             output = input++;

             output++;           //RIGHT
             output = input++;
        }
        return PortAudio.PaStreamCallbackResult.paContinue;
    }

    unsafe private void btnStream_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Dichiarazioni
        IntPtr* input;
        IntPtr* output;
        uint frameCount;
        PortAudio.PaStreamCallbackTimeInfo timeInfo;
        PortAudio.PaStreamCallbackFlags statusFlags;
        IntPtr* userData;

        IntPtr stream;

        PortAudio.PaError err = PortAudio.Pa_Initialize();
        if (err != PortAudio.PaError.paNoError)
            PortAudio.Pa_Terminate();

        err = PortAudio.Pa_OpenDefaultStream(out stream, 
                                                      1,
                                                      1,
               (uint)PortAudio.PaSampleFormat.paFloat32,
                                                  44100,
                 PortAudio.paFramesPerBufferUnspecified,
 new PortAudio.PaStreamCallbackDelegate(StreamCallback),  //In this row it gives me the error
                                          (IntPtr)null);
```

If anyone knows how to help me I would be very grateful, thank you.

Comment: Maybe this would help: https://vstnet.codeplex.com/discussions/246206.

Comment: thanks for the reply! 
I followed your advice. I followed the post that you linked me, but it continues to give me the exact same error in the same line of code. 
**It may be that I've some setting wrong?** 
Maybe something stupid that I didn't set in the program (using **Visual Studio 2010**). I don't know what to think anymore..

Comment: I really can't do anything more then that as I don't know a thing about portaudio library... Although it called to my attention that your StreamCallback doesn't match the delegate definition. Your input, output and userdata arguments should be of the type `IntPtr` instead of `IntPtr*`.

Comment: Thank you very much in fact just what the error was!
The pointers I needed in that format otherwise the increase would not let me do, but I managed to convert without problems within the function.

Comment: Ill be answering knowing that then.

Answer (score 1):

Your input, output and userdata arguments should be of the type `IntPtr` instead of `IntPtr*`

Also I think you don't really are making a copy in your callback method. I really think you should use some of the [`IntPtr`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.intptr%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) methods. I never used unsafe types in .Net but looking at a [copy sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.intptr.topointer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) I believe that your algorithm would be something like:

```
unsafe public PortAudio.PaStreamCallbackResult StreamCallback(
        IntPtr input,  IntPtr output,  uint frameCount,
        ref PortAudio.PaStreamCallbackTimeInfo timeInfo,
        PortAudio.PaStreamCallbackFlags statusFlags,
        IntPtr userData) 
{
    byte *src = (byte *)input.ToPointer();
    byte *dst = (byte *)output.ToPointer();
    for (int i = 0; i < frameCount; i++)
    {
         *dst++ = *src++;//in c this could be written dst[i] = src[i] maybe you can try that.
    }
    return PortAudio.PaStreamCallbackResult.paContinue;
}
```

**Edit**: According to Hans Passant you should also save your delegate in a field so it doesn't get garbage collected. But **AFAIK** it would be enough to store it in a variable because garbage collection doesn't clean your object as long as there is at least one reference to it. This only applies if the callback occurs in the same method where it is defined though, otherwise you should store in a field as he stated.

```
unsafe private void btnStream_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Dichiarazioni
    IntPtr* input;
    IntPtr* output;
    uint frameCount;
    PortAudio.PaStreamCallbackTimeInfo timeInfo;
    PortAudio.PaStreamCallbackFlags statusFlags;
    IntPtr* userData;

    IntPtr stream;

    PortAudio.PaError err = PortAudio.Pa_Initialize();
    var callback = new PortAudio.PaStreamCallbackDelegate(StreamCallback);
    if (err != PortAudio.PaError.paNoError)
        PortAudio.Pa_Terminate();

    err = PortAudio.Pa_OpenDefaultStream(out stream,  1, 1,
           (uint)PortAudio.PaSampleFormat.paFloat32,
                                              44100,
             PortAudio.paFramesPerBufferUnspecified,
                          callback,
                                      (IntPtr)null);
```

Comment: You should also mention that he needs to store the delegate object in a field of the class or a static variable so it cannot be garbage collected.

Comment: @Hans Passant I think you are talking about err variable (since it is the only variable that makes use of a delegate). I assumed that err was going to be used and discarded since I don't have a clue what Op intended to do with it.

Comment: No, I'm talking about the Pa_OpenDefaultStream() call.  He creates the delegate object with *new*, there's no reference to it after the call so it is going to be garbage collected.  That's a hard crash when the native code makes the callback.

Comment: I had to think many times of what you were saying and I concluded you were right (Could it possible be a crime doubting of you?). But I am used to scenarios where my **managed** callbacks are used straight way.